# cant download new patch APSB22-48

Tags: security-patch, magento2.4.2-p2

how can I download the patch in url
https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-48.html

I am using adobe commerce

```
bin/magento --version
```

Magento CLI 2.4.2-p2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APSB22-48 does not affect Magento 2.4.2 if all applicable security hotfixes are applied. In other words, there are no patches, or hotfixes for APSB22-48 for Magento 2.4.2

You can see the full list of affected and not affected here:
https://magetu.com/adobe-commerce-and-magento-open-source-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698-and-hotfix-patches-for-2-3-7-p3-2-3-7-p4/

Answer (score 1):

This is not the patch. I Think this is the only security update from Adobe that you should upgrade your Magento version to enhance your Security. I already confirmed about this from Adobe also.